# Animate Position with Fadeout

Tags: jquery

I am trying to accomplish the following.

The Setup:
Images inside divs that have overflow set to hidden.

The Desired Effect:
When the div is hovered over, image should move up inside the div.
When the images top or bottom meets the top or bottom of the div, the image should reverse direction.
When the mouse leaves the div, the image should stop incrementally, not suddenly.

The Problem:
I cannot find a way to use intervals for multiple elements on the page and producing an infinite loop is just bad programming.
I can't seem to get the image to reverse directions properly.

The Code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
        var posts = $(".post");
        var post_images = $(".post > img");
        var post_details = $(".job_focus");

        var pan_scan = function(e){
            event.stopPropagation();
            var image = $(e.target);
            var image_height = image.height();
            var original_offset;
            var first_run = "true";


            var move_image = function(){
                var fadeout = image.attr("fadeout");
                var direction = image.attr("direction");

                if (fadeout == "false"){
                    console.log("hover animation");
                    var image_offset = parseInt(image.css("top"));
                    var direction = image.attr("direction");

                    if (image_offset - 2 < -(image_height - 160)){
                        image.attr("direction", "+");
                    } else if (image_offset + 2 > -150){
                        image.attr("direction", "-");
                    };

                    image.animate({"top": direction + "=2px"}, 1, "linear");
                } else if (fadeout == "true"){
                    console.log("fadeout animation");
                    if (first_run == "true") {

                        original_offset = image.offset().top;

                        if (direction == "-"){
                            var image_stop = original_offset - 20;
                        } else if (direction == "+") {
                            var image_stop = original_offset + 20;
                        };

                        first_run = "false";
                    };

                    current_offset = image.offset().top;

                    if (direction == "-"){
                        var image_difference = (current_offset - image_stop )/10;
                        console.log(image_stop);
                        console.log(current_offset);
                        console.log(image_difference);
                    } else if (direction == "+") {
                        var image_difference = (image_stop -  current_offset)/10;
                        console.log("test");
                    } else {
                        console.log("direction failed");
                        console.log(image);
                    };

                    if (image_difference > 1){
                        image.animate({"top": direction + "=" + image_difference}, 1, "easeOutExpo");
                    } else {
                        image.stop(true, true);
                        image.attr({"fadeout": false, "animate": false});
                        first_run = "true";
                    };
                }

                var animate = image.attr("animate");
                if (animate == "true") {
                    move_image();
                } else {
                    image.attr("animate", true);
                }
            };

            move_image();
        };

        var un_pan_scan = function(e){
            var image = $(e.target);
            image.attr("fadeout", true);
        };

        post_images.each(function(){
            // Moves images to the center of the div, sets initial values for movement, and sets the mouseenter and mouseleave handlers
            $(this).css({'top': -($(this).height()/2)}).attr({"direction": "-", "fadeout": "false", "animate": "true"}).hover(pan_scan, un_pan_scan);
        });
    });
```

Can anybody help me out here?  I feel like I am really over-complicating this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to start over and come up with a way to have multiple setIntervals that each reference the correct object.

This is what I came up with:

```
var intervals = {};

function object_hover(e){
var num = $(e.target).attr("num");

intervals[num] = window.setInterval(function(){do_stuff_here()}, 1000);
};

function object_blur(e){
var num = $(e.target).attr("post_num");

clearInterval(intervals[post_num]);
};

objects.each(function(){$(this.hover(post_hover, post_blur)});
```

Just going to work from there, should turn out fine.